# pandas extractall() is not extracting all cases given a regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a nested list of strings which I would like to extract them the date. The date format is:

> Two numbers (from `01` to `12`) hyphen tree letters (a valid month)
>   hyphen two numbers, for example: `08-Jan—07` or `03-Oct—01`

I tried to use the following regex:

```
r'\d{2}(—|-)(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2,4}'
```

Then I tested it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'blobs':['6-Feb- 1 4 Facebook’s virtual-reality division created a 3-EBÚ7 11 network of 500 free demo stations in Best Buy stores to give people a taste of VR using the Oculus Rift 90 GT 48 headset. But according to a Wednesday report from Business Insider, about 200 of the demo stations will close after low interest from consumers. 17-Feb-2014',
                         'I think in a store environment getting people to sit down and go through that experience of getting a headset on and getting set up is quite a difficult thing to achieve,” said Geoff Blaber, a CCS Insight analyst. 29—Oct-2012 Blaber 32 FAX 2978 expects that it will get easier when companies can convince  18-Oct-12 credit cards. '
                            ]})
df
```

Then:

```
df['blobs'].str.extractall(r'\d{2}(—|-)(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2,4}')
```

Nevertheless, they are not working. The previous regex doesn't give me anything (i.e. just hypens `-`):

```
    Col
0   NaN
1    -
2    -
3   NaN
4   NaN
5    -
...
n    -
```

**How can I fix them in order to get?:**

```
           Col
0 6-Feb-14, 17-Feb-2014
1 29—Oct-2012, 18-Oct-12
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried to:

```
import re
df['col'] = df.blobs.apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d{2}(—|-)(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2,4}',x))
s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['col']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
s.name = "col"
df = df.drop('col')
df
```

Nevertheless I also got:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5e9a34bd159f> in <module>()
      3 s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['col']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
      4 s.name = "col"
----> 5 df = df.drop('col')
      6 df

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, level, inplace, errors)
   1905                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   1906             else:
-> 1907                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   1908             dropped = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   1909             try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   3260             if errors != 'ignore':
   3261                 raise ValueError('labels %s not contained in axis' %
-> 3262                                  labels[mask])
   3263             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   3264         return self.delete(indexer)

ValueError: labels ['col'] not contained in axis
```

Comment: `(:?)` is a typo, right? Try `r"\b\d{2}-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2}\b"`. If there can be en- or em-dashes, replace `-` with `[-–—]`.

Comment: At a glance, your regexes don't match hyphens.

Comment: If you want `6-Feb` to be accepted, then you need to allow for _one_ number upfront rather than two. e.g. `\d{1,2}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the help!.. I got: `ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups`

Comment: Sure, add it (I forgot it): `r"\b(\d{2}-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec‌​)-\d{2})\b"`

Comment: Thanks again Wiktor... I am getting false positives with your appproach... for example: `35 FAX 2978` and `90 GT 48`. What about adding coherence to the regex?.. I tried this one:

Comment: `r"^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, however is not working...

Comment: SO inserts garbage chars into comments, do not copy from here. See https://regex101.com/r/IRqoon/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that one actually worked. Nevertheless, it is not adding the two dates in the same cell. For example https://regex101.com/r/IRqoon/2

Comment: @johndoe: replace `extract` with `extractall`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I will accept your answer could you post it below in order to accept it?... Also when I do `extractall` I got `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

Comment: I guess the issue is related to the fact that some entries do not match the pattern.

Comment: Just read there is [`pandas.Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)-  try `df['blobs'].str.findall(r'\b(\d{2}[—–-](?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[—–-]\d{2,4})\b')` (again, some garbage symbols here). For the items that have no match, it returns an empty list. Right now, I see `df['Col1'] = df['blobs'].str.findall(r'\b(\d{2}-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2,4})\b')` yields something close.

Comment: Thanks again for the help @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I posted an answer after testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) or [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), the *captured* substrings are returned, not the whole matches. So, you need to make sure you capture (i.e. add `(` and `)` around) the part of pattern you need to grab.

Now, several expected matches in your rows make it more difficult to do with `extractall`, it seems you may use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) that may return the *whole matches* if no capturing group is defined in the pattern.

Use

```
rx = r'\b\d{1,2}[-–—](?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[-–—](?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b'
df['Col'] = df['blobs'].str.findall(rx).apply(','.join)
```

The `.apply(','.join)` will convert lists to comma-separated strings in `Col` column.

The pattern means:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `[-–—]` - a hyphen, em- or en-dash
- `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)`  - any of the 12 month shortened names
- `[-–—]` - a  hyphen, em- or en-dash
- `(?:\d{4}|\d{2})` - 4 or 2 digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: Thanks, just another quick question... in case of matching upper and lower is it ok to add `(?i)`?. for example: r'\b\d{1,2}[-–—]((?i)?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[-–—](?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b'

Comment: In Python *`re`*, the place of the inline `(?i)` modifier does not make any difference. If you place it at the end, it will make the *whole* pattern case insensitive. Use `rx = r'(?i)\b\d{1,2}[-–—](?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[-–—](?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b'`

Comment: Thanks your answer really help me to clarify the extractall issue